# Trying to install Storybook into my Atom project

Tags: atom-editor, storybook

I'm trying to install Storybook in my project's root directory through the Atom terminal, but the  command that I'm using with Storybook CLI to install is not working. How can I resolve this issue?

```
PS C:\Users\khari\github\pancake-frontend> npx sb init
npx : The term 'npx' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that
the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ npx sb init
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (npx:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: 1. Atom has no default terminal, it might help to specify which third-party terminal package you're using
2. It looks like you don't have NodeJS installed or use an old version that doesn't include `npx`

Comment: @idleberg I have installed NodeJS and I have installed the PlatformIO package on Atom, if that's ok.